# How to test @PreDestroy and @Bean methods inside a class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing

I have the following methods inside a class

```
@Bean(name = "boggle")
    public BoggleImpl createBoggleClient() {
        BoggleBuilder builder = new BoggleBuilder()
                            .setRegistryId(getRegistryId())
                            .setRegistryPassword(getPassword())
                           
        return new BoggleFeatureImpl(builder.build());
    }
```

and am using the bean inside a class such as

```
class A {
    private final Boggle boggle;

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        if (boggle != null) {
            boggle.closeConnection();
        }
    }

}
```

Now my code coverage in unit tests show these methods as not covered. Not sure what can i do to cover these methods. Any pointers on the same.

Comment: could you also share those tests?

Answer (score 2):

Using `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` the `ApplicationContext` is shared between all the running test cases and the `@PreDestroy` is called only when the `ApplicationContext` is closed.

Spring has this behavior because you can be working in a big application which has a slow startup and can be costly to create a new context.

You could annotate your test method with the `@DirtiesContext` annotation.

From it's [**javadoc**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html):

> Test annotation which indicates that the ApplicationContext associated
> with a test is dirty and should therefore be closed and removed from
> the context cache.
>
> Use this annotation if a test has modified the
> context — for example, by modifying the state of a singleton bean,
> modifying the state of an embedded database, etc. Subsequent tests
> that request the same context will be supplied a new context.

Answer (score 2):

In this example, `class A` must be a spring bean. Methods annotated with `@PreDestroy` are called by the application context when it gets closed. Usually, this happens when the application gets shut down gracefully.

So basically you can "simulate" the situation of closing the application context even from a simple unit test, you don't have to start spring in the test for this.

Treat this method as a regular method with some code regardless of the fact that its called by spring:

```
class A {
   private final Boggle boggle;
    public class A(Boggle boggle) 
    {this.boggle = boggle;}
    
    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        if (boggle != null) {
            boggle.closeConnection();
        }
    }

}
```

Then a test can look like this:

```
class ATest {
   
   @Test
   public void test_boggle_closes_connection_when_the_bean_gets_destroyed() {
       // given:
       Boggle boggle  =  Mockito.mock(Boggle.class);
       A underTest = new A(boggle);
       // when:
       underTest.destroy();
       // then: verify that boggle closes connection
       Mockito.verify(boggle, times(1)).closeConnection();  
   }

}
```